# Form Input always returns value, added to +URL function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Creating a form that takes input and adds it to URL. If no value is provided, it's not added.

The text field input always triggers as "subject" present. Is there a way to remove it (not add to +url) if the value of the form is "".

Form Code:

```
<input name="subject" id="subject" value="" type="text">
```

URL building code:

```
 if( "{subject}" != "{"+"subject"+"}" ) { url = url + "&subject={subject}"; }
```

Every url comes out with **&subject=**&foo....

Is there a way to do an if="" else="value"

Should I do a PHP function prior to the JS?

Comment: are you using GET or Post method to relay data

Comment: post - but I figured out how to do it in Chronoforms (joomla), using a check box to enable/disable the field. Was about to delete this - thanks for looking in on it!